# How can I move to the next index?

Tags: python

I want to move from guesser[0] to guesser[1] if the solution matches the first letter from guesser and so on but I just can't figure it out

```py
import string
list = []
guesser = "bomba"

while True:
    for characters in string.printable:   
        solution = ''.join(list) + characters
        print(solution)
        if solution == guesser[0]:
            list.append(solution)
            break
```

I've tried

```py
import string
list = []
guesser = "bomba"
index = 0
while True:
    for characters in string.printable:   
        solution = ''.join(list) + characters
        print(solution)
        if solution == guesser[index]:
            list.append(solution)
            index += 1
            break
```

Comment: Take incrementing of `index` outside of your `if`.

Comment: As an aside - don't name a variable `list` or any other soft keyword for a built-in function (i.e., don't name ints `int` or floats `float`).  After your line `list = []`, you will not be able to use the `list()` command to convert anything into a list, because you have replaced that built-in reference with a new reference to an instance of a list.

Comment: @PM77-1 And where should I place it then? That seemed the best place to put it

Comment: @nigh_anxiety Thank you for the info it was called something else before I posted it anyway

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve in more detail? What kind of an end result are you looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is that with the code as written, you will never be able to match on any character of `guesser` after the guesser[0] because `solution` will be more than one character.
After it matches the first 'b', and index += 1, then it's going to be checking if guesser[1] (i.e. 'o') is == "bo", so it will never be true.

Try this:

```
import string
answer = []
guesser = "bomba"
while len(answer) != len(guesser):  # We need this to end someday.
   index = len(answer)
   for character in string.printable:   
        if character == guesser[index]:
            answer.append(character)
            break    # Exit the for loop
   else:  # If the for loop completes without finding a match
       print(f"The character at guesser[{index}] is not in string.printable")
       break  # Exit the while loop

print(f"Answer found : {''.join(answer)}")
```